# Third Panel doesn't show up

Tags: java, panel

I have this problem where a third panel isn't fully showing up. When my mouse is hovered over a button, the button keeps blinking and same goes to a Text Field. However, Panel 1 and Panel 2 which is before Panel 3 (problematic panel) works fine.

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws MalformedURLException {

URL url = new URL("file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/b3b1acfe66b18d45dcf39d2ca26030c0%20(1).gif");
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);

URL urlPodium = new URL("https://www.isora.org/images/Images/PagestaticImages/PodiumX500.jpg");
Icon iconPodium = new ImageIcon(urlPodium);

JLabel Runner = new JLabel(icon);
Runner.setBounds(0, 0, 960, 960);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Marathon");
frame.setSize(960,960);


JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
JLabel Name = new JLabel("Enter Runner Name:");
JLabel Time = new JLabel ("Enter Runner Time: ");
JTextField runnerName = new JTextField();
runnerName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,24));
Format timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
JFormattedTextField runnerTime = new JFormattedTextField (timeFormat);
runnerTime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,24));
JLabel formatEnter = new JLabel("            (Format:mm:ss)            ");
JButton Submit = new JButton("Submit");

Panel.setBounds(0, 0, 160, 180);
JLayeredPane root = frame.getLayeredPane();
root.add(Runner, 1);
root.add(Panel, 0);
Panel.setAlignmentX(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

Panel.add(Name);
Panel.add(runnerName);
Panel.add(Time);
Panel.add(runnerTime);
Panel.add(formatEnter);
Panel.add(Submit);
frame.setVisible(true);


      JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
      JLabel Name2 = new JLabel("Enter Runner 2 Name:");
      JLabel Time2 = new JLabel ("Enter Runner 2 Time: ");
      JTextField runnerName2 = new JTextField();
      runnerName2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,24));
      Format timeFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
      JFormattedTextField runnerTime2 = new JFormattedTextField (timeFormat2);
      runnerTime2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,24));
      JLabel formatEnter2 = new JLabel("            (Format:mm:ss)            ");
      JButton Submit2 = new JButton("Submit");

       Panel2.setBounds(0, 180, 160, 180);
       JLayeredPane root2 = frame.getLayeredPane();
       root2.add(Runner, 1);
       root2.add(Panel2, 0);
       Panel2.setAlignmentX(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

       Panel2.add(Name2);
       Panel2.add(runnerName2);
       Panel2.add(Time2);
       Panel2.add(runnerTime2);
       Panel2.add(formatEnter2);
       Panel2.add(Submit2);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       
       
               JPanel Panel3 = new JPanel();
               JLabel Name3 = new JLabel("Enter Runner 3 Name:");
               JLabel Time3 = new JLabel ("Enter Runner 3 Time: ");
               JTextField runnerName3 = new JTextField();
               runnerName3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,24));
               Format timeFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
               JFormattedTextField runnerTime3 = new JFormattedTextField (timeFormat3);
               runnerTime3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,24));
               JLabel formatEnter3 = new JLabel("            (Format:mm:ss)            ");
               JButton Submit3 = new JButton("Submit");
 
               Panel3.setBounds(0, 360, 160, 180);
               JLayeredPane root3 = frame.getLayeredPane();
               root3.add(Runner, 1);
               root3.add(Panel3, 0);
               
               Panel3.setAlignmentX(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
 
               Panel3.add(Name3);
               Panel3.add(runnerName3);
               Panel3.add(Time3);
               Panel3.add(runnerTime3);
               Panel3.add(formatEnter3);
               Panel3.add(Submit3);
               frame.setVisible(true);
               Submit3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
      System.out.println("Runner 1 Name " + runnerName.getText());
      System.out.println("Runner 1 Time " + runnerTime.getText());
      System.out.println("Runner 2 Name " + runnerName2.getText());
      System.out.println("Runner 2 Time " + runnerTime2.getText());
      System.out.println("Runner 3 Name " + runnerName3.getText());
      System.out.println("Runner 3 Time " + runnerTime3.getText());
      
      
    }
  });}


     
}
```

My code is pasted above. If anyone could please take a look and help me out, that would be great. Cheers!

Comment: Also, you are using a JLayeredPane incorrectly. The constraints you specify are incorrect. Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for working examples. I'm not sure why you try to use the layered pane of the frame. Rarely would you do that. Normally you just add components to the content pane of the frame. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. All I can suggest is that all components should be added tot he frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Comment: i wont discuss code quality, it is another topic, but panel3 shoud be (and is) displayed

Comment: please provide minimal version of not worked code, so we can spot what's wrong here